# get the coefficients and intercept value of the last X days of data from a lm model in R and repeat for the next day and create a dataframe with it

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

I would like to create like a last X days coefficients and intercept and paste that on that day then move to the next day and paste again the last X days coefficients and intercept and so on.

I use the dataset that comes with R called economics

this is the code I have so far

```
library(plyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(repr)

dat <- economics

drops <- c("date")
dat <- dat[ , !(names(dat) %in% drops)]


cols = c('pce', 'pop', 'psavert', 'uempmed')

pre_proc_val <- preProcess(dat[,cols], method = c("center", "scale"))


dat[,cols] = predict(pre_proc_val, dat[,cols])




###### Linear Regression

number_days = 30

lr = lm(unemploy ~ uempmed + psavert + pop + pce, data = dat)


dataframecoefficients  <- as.data.frame(lr$coefficients)
```

this code will give me the coefficients for all the data but what I need is the grab the data from the first row until the value of `number_days` calculate the coefficients and intercept of that piece of data and paste it next to row 30, then it will move to row 31 ad repeat the process and paste the values on row 31 and so on until it reaches the end of the file

the end result would look like this

```
        ce           pop       psavert      uempmed    unemploy   (Intercept) uempmed psavert pop pce 
  

27   -1.1827734   -1.4739945  1.0231339  -0.951801535  3040            NA       NA      NA    NA   NA
28   -1.1812833   -1.4682151  0.9556616  -1.00050309   3049            NA       NA      NA    NA   NA
29   -1.1807210   -1.4628175  1.0231339  -0.927450756  2856            NA       NA      NA    NA   NA
30   -1.1800743   -1.4580468  1.0906062  -0.976152314  2884           1771      2343   3244   232  -34
31   -1.1784155   -1.4533034  1.0906062  -0.976152314  3201           1770      2234   3100   200  -40
..   ..           ...          ....       ....          ...          ...         ...    ...    ..   ..
```

is there an efficient to do this with dplyr or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way in base R :

```
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
new_cols <- c('Intercept', paste0(cols, '_predict'))
dat[new_cols] <- NA

inds <- nrow(dat) - number_days

dat[(number_days+1):nrow(dat), new_cols] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(inds), function(x) {
  lr = lm(unemploy ~ uempmed + psavert + pop + pce, data = dat[x:(x + number_days - 1), ])
  t(lr$coefficients)
}))
```